# High Overseer Campbell Meeting Objective Bugged?

Tags: dishonored

I'm playing the High Overseer Campbell mission.  I've made it to the meeting room without being detected, but every time I enter the room, without exception, Campbell and guy I'm trying to save instantly cut off their conversation, Campbell shouts "I'll find you!", and then both of them run out of the room.

What gives?

I've reloaded several times from different save locations.  This seems to happen no matter what I do.  Is this intended behavior?  (I can't imagine it is).

**What can I do to prevent High Overseer Campbell from running out of the meeting room immediately after I enter it?  Is this a bug?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior (I suspect it is if you linger too long before getting to his chambers), but fortunately, it's not too big of a deal. If you're intent on minimizing casualties and completing the optional objective, you can open the door to trigger the event, then hide. After a while, the optional objective will trigger as the target leaves the area. At this point, you should be able to track down Campbell in his hidden chamber in the basement. You can get in by activating the gem in the eye of the bust across from the door to the Kennels.

Comment: This is what I eventually did.

Comment: Adding some \r\n s will *really* increase the readability of your answer. You're a senior here, so I leave the edit to your hands.

Answer (score 0):

Unconfirmed, but I've read the bug is triggered by opening the gate at the entrance of Holger Square...

[EDIT] I reloaded a previous save, did not opened the gate and I can confirm the bug does not trigger.

Comment: It must be something else then, I used Blink to get past the gate without opening it and still got the bug.